# Can someone tell me why this animation is only being executed once? (Javafx)

Tags: java, javafx

I am running into an issue where eH is only being executed once and I am not sure what is wrong. I read the javadocs on the Timeline and I don't see where I am going wrong. Hopefully an extra pair of eyes could see what is wrong. Thanks.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Demo extends Application {
    GridPane gp = new GridPane();
    Label label1 = new Label("Label 1");
    Label label2 = new Label("Label 2");
    Label label3 = new Label("Label 3");
    Label label4 = new Label("Label 4");
    Scene scene;
    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    VBox vbox2 = new VBox();
    Image image = new Image("image.png");
    ImageView iv = new ImageView();
    Rectangle first = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
    Rectangle second = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
    Rectangle third = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
    Rectangle forth = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
    Button b1 = new Button("Enter1");

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label1, label2, label3, label4);
        gp.add(vbox, 0, 0);
        vbox2.getChildren().addAll(b1,new Button("Enter2"),
                new Button("Enter3"),new Button("Enter4"),new Button("Enter5") );
        gp.add(vbox2, 1, 0);
        iv.setImage(image);
        //iv.setFitWidth(700);
        //iv.setFitHeight(300);
        iv.setPreserveRatio(true);
        iv.setSmooth(true);
        iv.setCache(true);
        gp.add(iv, 3, 0);


        first.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        second.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        third.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        forth.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        gp.add(first, 4, 0);
        gp.add(second, 5, 0);
        gp.add(third, 4, 1);
        gp.add(forth, 5, 1);
        boolean x = false;
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> eH = e -> {
             if (x == false) {
                first.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                second.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                third.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                forth.setFill(Color.WHITE);
             }
             else {
                first.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                second.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                third.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                forth.setFill(Color.BLACK);
             }
             };


        Timeline animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), eH));
         animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
         animation.play();

         b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    animation.stop();
                    animation.play();
                }
            });

        scene = new Scene(gp, 700, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Lab 24");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The event handler `eH` is executed multiple times, there is just nothing for it do the subsequent times it is executed as it sets the same fills on the same rectangles all of the time.  To show that it is getting executed, place the statement `System.out.print("*");` inside the event handler, you will see a `*` symbol printed to the console every half a second.

Answer (score 0):

The animation keeps playing... but it's doing nothing. The first time `x=false`, performs some changes, but then `x` is always false, and there's nothing to change.

For instance, if you want to create a back and forwards indefinite effect, do this:

```
boolean x = false;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ...
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> eH = e -> {
         if (x == false) {
            first.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            second.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            third.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            forth.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            x=true;
         }
         else {
            first.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            second.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            third.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            forth.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            x=false;
         }
    };

    Timeline animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), eH));
    animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animation.play();
```

Or if you want just one single cycle, remove `animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);`, and you will get one cycle every time you click the button `b1`.